# How to simulate mouse click in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, fullcalendar, selenium-ide

I want to test my [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) with Selenuim Ide but i can't figure how can I simulate a mouse click on my calendar.

When I manually do left button click on some time in fullcalendar then [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/) event is fired. In selenium IDE I've tried next commands, but it's not working  - select event is not fired :

```
selenium.FireEvent("xpath=(//tr[@data-time='08:00:00'])", "click");
selenium.Click("xpath=(//tr[@data-time='08:00:00'])");
```

Example of element that I want to click :

```
<tr data-time="08:00:00">
    <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 47px;">
        <span>08:30</span></td><td class="fc-widget-content">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Update: The test is ok but, fullcalendar can't detect this click
[image]

**Update2 :** To be more clear, for example I have a simple calendar here 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cof6f48L/). Is it possible to simulate a mouse click on some time of the day in calendar ?

Comment: Provided element seem to be non-clickable. Which exact element you want to click? Also show `XPath` you tried

Comment: @Andersson, I've updated the question. I dont know which element exactly I should to click. I just want call select event of fullcandar

Comment: hmm... I can hardly understand how you want to call select event... There is no elements to interact with

Comment: @Andersson, fullcalendar in some way links the click on this item with select event and I don't want know how, I want just programmatically make a click on this item like the user do with mouse :)

Comment: And what happens, when you click on it manually `like the user do with mouse` ? :) As I clearly see there is no events mapped to this element and it is non-clickable...

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found a solution :

```
selenium.MouseDownAt("xpath=(//tr[@data-time='10:00:00']/td[2])", "2,2");
selenium.MouseUp("xpath=(//tr[@data-time='10:00:00'])");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find that "click" or "clickAt" command does not work to your test case, you can try **a series of "mouse" commands**, like "mouseDown", "mouseUp" and so on. 
It depends on what event the element you clicked has listened.
For example, maybe the element is listening mousedown/up event in this case. Although you clicked the element and IDE recorded "click" command, the command couldn't work as well.

And, if you need, please try to use the tool, SideeX, the extended version of Selenium IDE. 
I have some new ideas about clicking problems in this tool and make the test case flexible. 
Here is the link to [SideeX](http://sideex.org/) and there are more details about the tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capybara with the Selenium Driver for Ruby acceptance testing, then you have a page helper, which gives you context to the current page. The driver method of page will give you access to the currently running driver (as specified by Capybara.default_driver or Capybara.current_driver). This would be Selenium by default if not otherwise specified. Now that we have the driver we access the Firefox browser via the browser helper method, which gives us access to find_element. There is an important note about 'find_element' to be cognizant of. There is a bug in bugzilla.mozilla wherein tr nodes are rendered as invisible and will raise an exception 'element cannot be scrolled into view'. The solution is to access the td element of the tr element, as so:

```
page.driver.browser.find_element(:xpath, "//tr[@data-time='10:00:00']/td[2]").click
```